# How to apply round rectuangular shape to the parsed image from android?

Tags: android

I'm parsing the image from the url, i want to display the corner of parsed image as roundrect(similar to figure2) but i'm not able to do that, can anyone guide me regarding on this, My code for parsing the image from url is

```
 img_value = new URL(VAL4[arg0]);
 Log.v("Image_Url1",img_value.toString());
 try{
    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
    img.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.v(TAG,"error   "+e);
}
```

Figure 2
[image]

Figure1
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this URL a try: [Draw circular region over bitmap](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg30548.html)

In essence what you want to do is clip the original bitmap by applying a path to the canvas in which you draw.